# Can I use local storage for a mobile HTML5 webapp as a fallback when user loses internet access?

Tags: mobile, local-storage

I'm making a mobile HTML5 webapp and I'm wondering if I can use local storage to enable users to still use the app when they lose internet access.

The basic idea would be that when they have wi-fi / 3G they download the HTML and data, but when they lose internet access they can at least access the last version with old cached data (with a warning that data may not be up to date until they get internet access again).

Is this possible with local storage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly. One of the purposes with `localStorage` is to enable offline applications.

you can check ([see here for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.onLine)):

```
window.navigator.onLine
```

to see if you are online or offline, or simply:

```
window.addEventListener("offline", offlineFunc, false)
window.addEventListener("online", onlineFunc, false)
```

and if offline you serve the stored content from `localStorage` by updating the page partially.

Another way of doing this is to use a `cache manifest`.

Here you can define which files shall be available if browser become offline, and which require network and so forth.

See here for details on that:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5
http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html

Besides from `localStorage` you can also use `IndexedDB` which also allow you to store `Blobs` (or files) ([File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/) is coming, currently only for Chrome).